# Acess values xml file from animation xml file

Tags: java, android, xml

Inside my res/animator/backward.xml file, how can I acess a value from
res/values/dimens.xml ?

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:duration="@dimen/anim_time" 
/>
```

values file:

```
<resources>
    <integer name = "anim_time">500</integer>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is access **integer** value as **dimen**.
Below code will work without any issue:

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:duration="@integer/anim_time" />
```

Please refer to [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#attr_android:duration) docs about `duration` attribute:

```
This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.
```

So, if your value is integer it's type should be `integer`. Actually, dimens values are not allowed per above documentation.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. However, my Intellij IDE cannot recognize this form as and does not link to the ressource. But its more important that it works :D

Comment: My Intellij Idea 13.1.4 recognizes that value and shows actual value instead of '@integer/anim_time'.

Comment: Now my IDEA (also 13.1.4) recognizes the value too, but still doesn't link to the dimensions ressource file...

Comment: @Brian have you tried to mark res directory as 'resource root'? For me it help sometimes